# handling errors inside code first migrations

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I have the following inside my Up()

```cs
public override void Up()
{      
    try
    {
        Sql("drop index [IX_SalesInvoiceLine] on dbo.SalesInvoiceLines"); 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignored
    }
    string sql = @"CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SalesInvoiceLine] ON [dbo].[SalesInvoiceLines] ( [SalesInvoice_Id] ASC, [seqNo] ASC) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]";
    Sql(sql);
 }
```

When I step through the code in the debugger I can step through each line.

However when I run the migration I get a message

```
"Cannot drop the index'dbo.SalesInvoiceLines_IXSalesInvoiceLine' , 
because it does not exist or you do not have permission"
```

Why is this error being thrown?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Up procedure is feeding commands to the migration to run later.
Thus the try catch is not relevant here.

Comment: I'm running into the same scenario, the DBAs created and removed indexes outside of entity framework. So I was hoping to check if objects exist before droping them.  Is there a strategy you know of that I should pursue?  Besides beating the dbas over the head....